# Create trigger for several rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table `users` AND `orders`. After every UPDATE row in `orders`. I want update `DATA` in `users` table namely concat(OLD.DATA + ID which was updated).

```
Table 'users'.

ID  NAME    DATA
1   John    1|2
2   Michael 3|4
3   Someone 5

Table 'orders'.

ID  USER    CONTENT
1   1       ---
2   1       ---
3   2       ---
4   2       ---
5   3       ---
```

For example:

```
SELECT `data` from `users` where `id` = 2; // Result: 3|4
UPDATE `orders` SET '...' WHERE `id` > 0;
**NEXT LOOP**
UPDATE `users` SET `data` = concat(OLD.data, ID.rowUpdated) WHERE `user` = 1;
UPDATE `users` SET `data` = concat(OLD.data, ID.rowUpdated) WHERE `user` = 1;
UPDATE `users` SET `data` = concat(OLD.data, ID.rowUpdated) WHERE `user` = 2;
UPDATE `users` SET `data` = concat(OLD.data, ID.rowUpdated) WHERE `user` = 2;
UPDATE `users` SET `data` = concat(OLD.data, ID.rowUpdated) WHERE `user` = 3;
```

Result:

```
SELECT data from users where id = 1; // Result: 1|2|1|2
SELECT data from users where id = 2; // Result: 3|4|3|4
SELECT data from users where id = 3; // Result: 5|5
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) .. ideally you should have a `user_order` table where you store the relations between a user and a order.

Comment: The question you linked is clearly relevant in this situation, but I don't see how his question is even remotely similar to the alleged "duplicate".

Comment: I have removed the Oracle tag as you appear to be using MySQL and not Oracle. Please make sure to properly tag your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are making the same mistake I made not too long ago, ie storing an array/object in a column.

I would recommend using the following tables in your scenario:

### users

```
+-----------+-----------+
|    id     | user_name |
+-----------+-----------+
|     1     |   John    |
+-----------+-----------+
|     2     |  Michael  | 
+-----------+-----------+
```

### orders

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+
|    id     | user_id   |date_ordered|   
+-----------+-----------+------------+
|     1     |     1     | 2019-03-05 |
+-----------+-----------+------------+
|     2     |     2     | 2019-03-05 |
+-----------+-----------+------------+
```

Where `user_id` is the foreign key to `users`

### sales

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
|    id     | order_id  |  item_sku  |    qty     |   price    |
+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
|     1     |     1     |    1001    |     1      |   2.50     |
+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
|     2     |     1     |    1002    |     2      |   3.00     |
+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
|     3     |     2     |    1001    |     2      |   2.00     |
+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
```

where `order_id` is the foreign key to `orders`

Now for the confusing part.  You will need to use a series of `JOIN`s to access the relevant data for each user.

```
SELECT 
t3.id AS user_id,
t3.user_name,
t1.id AS order_id,
t1.date_ordered,
SUM((t2.price * t2.qty)) AS order_total   
FROM orders t1
JOIN sales t2 ON (t2.order_id = t1.id)
LEFT JOIN users t3 ON (t1.user_id = t3.id)
WHERE user_id=1
GROUP BY order_id;
```

This will return:

```
+-----------+--------------+------------+------------+--------------+
|  user_id  |  user_name   |  order_id  |date_ordered|  order_total |   
+-----------+--------------+------------+------------+--------------+
|     1     |    John      |      1     | 2019-03-05 |     8.50     |
+-----------+--------------+------------+------------+--------------+
```

These type of `JOIN` statements should come up in basically any project using a relational database (that is, if you are designing your DB correctly).  Typically I create a `view` for each of these complicated queries, which can then be accessed with a simple `SELECT * FROM orders_view`

For example:

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW orders_view AS (

  SELECT 
  t3.id AS user_id,
  t3.user_name,
  t1.id AS order_id,
  t1.date_ordered,
  SUM((t2.price * t2.qty)) AS order_total   
  FROM orders t1
  JOIN sales t2 ON (t2.order_id = t1.id)
  LEFT JOIN users t3 ON (t1.user_id = t3.id)
  GROUP BY order_id
)
```

This can then be accessed by:

```
SELECT * FROM orders_view WHERE user_id=1;
```

Which would return the same results as the query above.

Depending on your needs, you will probably need to add a few more tables (`addresses`, `products` etc.) and several more rows to each of these tables.  Very often you will find that you need to `JOIN` 5+ tables into a view, and sometimes you might need to `JOIN` the same table twice.

I hope this helps despite it not exactly answering your question!

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a bad idea to update the USERS table after inserting into (or updating) the ORDERS table.  Avoid storing data twice.  In your case: you can always get all "order ids" for a user by querying the ORDERS table.  Thus, you don't need to store them in the USERS table (again). Example (tested with MySQL 8.0, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=61fbed275db729f4b7b74e7b507ee99a)):

**Tables and data**

```
create table users( id integer primary key, name varchar(30) ) ;

insert into users( id, name ) values
(1, 'John'),(2, 'Michael'),(3, 'Someone') ;

create table orders( 
  id integer primary key
, userid integer
, content varchar(3) references users (id) 
);

insert into orders ( id, userid, content ) values
 (101, 1, '---'),(102, 1, '---')
,(103, 2, '---'),(104, 2, '---'),(105, 3, '---') ;
```

Maybe a **VIEW** - similar to the one below - will do the trick. (Advantage: you don't need additional columns or tables.)

```
-- View
-- Inner SELECT: group order ids per user (table ORDERS).
-- Outer SELECT: fetch the user name (table USERS)
create or replace view userorders ( 
  userid, username, userdata 
)
as
select
  U.id, U.name, O.orders_
from ( 
  select 
    userid
  , group_concat( id order by id separator '|' )  as orders_
  from orders
  group by userid
) O join users U on O.userid = U.id ;
```

Once the view is in place, you can just SELECT from it, and you will always get the current "userdata" eg

```
select * from userorders ;

-- result 
userid  username    userdata
1       John        101|102
2       Michael     103|104
3       Someone     105


-- add some more orders
insert into orders ( id, userid, content ) values 
 (1000, 1, '***'),(4000, 1, '***'),(7000, 1, '***')
,(2000, 2, ':::'),(5000, 2, ':::'),(8000, 2, ':::')
,(3000, 3, '@@@'),(6000, 3, '@@@'),(9000, 3, '@@@') ;


select * from userorders ;

-- result
userid  username  userdata
1       John      101|102|1000|4000|7000
2       Michael   103|104|2000|5000|8000
3       Someone   105|3000|6000|9000
```